Re-connecting to Jupyter notebook session

I connect to GPU server with VPN and SSH.
Jupyter server runs as daemon
Start Jupyter notebook through web interface.
Start long model training.
VPN drops.
Reconnect to VPN and SSH, Jupyter server status: running
Jupyter notebook, of course, is dead. However, kernel must be running.

Is there a way to reconnect to Jupyter session?
Please help
Thank you

You need a feature called session resumption, being able to query existing running kernels and connect to it, vs start a new one. Colab and Colab Enterprise support this, I dont think Jupyter supports this out of the box. https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2833
